# How can I get POSIX time vector in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

```
time1 = '2016-01-01'
timelen = A vector of time lengths in hours 
time1_vec = ymd(time1) + dhours(timelen)
```

I am getting the Y-M-D, but these are hourly timesteps, and I would like to get `"2016-01-01 01:00:00 UTC", "2016-01-01 02:00:00 UTC"` etc in time1_vec.

How can I do it?

## NOTE

This works for me:

```
ymd(time1) + dhours(2)
[1] "2016-01-01 02:00:00 UTC"
```

## dput(timelen)

```
structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 
63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 
79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 
95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 
109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 
122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 
135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 
148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 
161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 
174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 
187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 
200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 
213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 
226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 
239), .Dim = 240L)
```

This is what I get:

```
time1_vec
  [1] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01"
  [7] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01"
 [13] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01"
 [19] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01"
 [25] "2016-01-02" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-02"
```

etc.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(paste0(time1, " 00:00:00"), tz = "UTC") + timelen*60*60`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seq.POSIXt`, using `lubridate` for `ymd_hm` only:

```
library(lubridate)
seq.POSIXt(from=ymd_hm('2016-01-01 00:00'), by="1 hour", length=24)


[1] "2016-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 01:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 02:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 03:00:00 UTC"
[5] "2016-01-01 04:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 05:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 06:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 07:00:00 UTC"
[9] "2016-01-01 08:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 09:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 10:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 11:00:00 UTC"
[13] "2016-01-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 13:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 14:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 15:00:00 UTC"
[17] "2016-01-01 16:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 17:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 18:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 19:00:00 UTC"
[21] "2016-01-01 20:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 21:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 22:00:00 UTC" "2016-01-01 23:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: The timelen comes from a file and may be discontinuous sometimes. So I would prefer to do it in a general way, rather than mentioning the length.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ymd_hms`:

```
time1 = "2016-01-01:00:00:00"
time1_vec = ymd_hms(time1) + dhours(timelen)
```

Comment: How can I avoid mentioning "2016-01-01:00:00:00"? I would prefer to keep it "2016-01-01"

Comment: Ah, actually try this: `time1_vec = ymd(time1) + dhours(1:240)`.  It seems that the structure function returns an array (given that you set the dims), whereas it works with vectors.

Comment: The timelen comes from a file and may be discontinuous sometimes. So I would prefer to do it in a general way, rather than mentioning 1:240.